# Dynamic Scope in C

Tags: c, dynamic, scoping

I just have a problem with C dynamic scoping in the following code. I am aware that C only uses static (lexical) scoping, but the problem asks to pretend that we are using dynamic scoping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 25;
int y = 15;
int z = 5;

static void func1(int z) {
   x += 20;
   y += 30;
   z += 40;
   printf("func1: x=%4d y=%4d z=%4d x+y+z=%d\n",x,y,z,x+y+z);
}

static void func2(void) {
  int z = 100;
  y += 30;
  z += 10;
  func1(20);
  printf("func2: x=%4d y=%4d z=%4d x+y+z=%d\n",x,y,z,x+y+z);
}

static void func3(int x) {
 x += 40;
 func2(); 
 printf("func3: x=%4d y=%4d z=%4d x+y+z=%d\n",x,y,z,x+y+z);
}

static int func4() {
  int y = 90;
  func3(80);
  printf("func4: x=%4d y=%4d z=%4d x+y+z=%d\n",x,y,z,x+y+z);
  return 1000;
}

int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
  int y = func4();
  z += 2000;
  printf("main: x=%4d y=%4d z=%4d x+y+z=%d\n",x,y,z,x+y+z);
}
```

The following is the result of all 5:

- func1: x = 140 y=? z =? x+y+z = 350
- func2: x = ?   y=? z =? x+y+z = 400
- func3: x = ?   y=? z =? x+y+z = 295
- func4: x = ?   y=? z =? x+y+z = 180
- main:  x = ?   y=? z =? x+y+z = 3030

From my understanding, we go from main first and then to the next function called. So, in main, we have:

- x = 25 (from global variable),
- y = 1000 (from return 1000 from func4), and
- z = 2005 (from global variable 5 + 2000)
- x + y +z = 25 + 1000 + 2005 = 3030 -> correct.

But, in the other functions, such as in func4:

- variable x = 25 (from main from global)
- y = 90  (from local variable)
- z = 5 (from global variable)
- x + y + z = 25 + 90 + 5 = 120 -> incorrect.

This problem persists on the other functions, where I think I find the correct for 1 or 2 variables but have no idea for the last one.

Comment: C doesn't use dynamic scoping. Scoping is lexical. "_variable x = 25 (from main from global)_": `x` is `90` in `func4`, because it refers to the local declaration `int x = 90;`, not the global `x`. `y` refers to the global variable, there is no local `y` in `func4`. The global `z` has been modified by `func2` by the time the `printf` in `func4` is reached, so it won't be `5`.

Comment: You probably incorrectly wrote the question, as @user17732522 explained, last part doesn't make sense. Regardless, use a debugger and go step by step, you can see which variable is in current scope and to what you are assigning stuff.

Comment: I should have put more specific detail of the question. Yes, I am aware of the fact that C does not use dynamic scoping. But, in this case, it asks to pretend that we are using dynamic scoping instead of static (lexical) scoping.